# Javaのテストでstub(mock)/テスト実行/assertionを綺麗に書きたい

Tags: java, junit

Javaに限った話では無いのかもしれませんが、単体テストを実装する際には、

- 関連するクラスのスタブやモックの作成コードのテスト準備コード
- テスト実行のコード
- assertionのコード

を記載していくかと思います。
だんだんとテストを書いていくと、上記3つが混ざってくる気がしています。

そこで、上記3つの内容が一目で分かるようなテストライブラリを探しているのですが、
ご存じの方は教えてください。

ライブラリのコードイメージは下記のようになります。

```
@Test
public void testHoge(){
   TestHelper.prepare({
      Hoge hoge = mock(Hoge.class)
      when(hoge.getXXX).thenReturn("hogehoge");
   }).execute({
      result(test.target());
   }).evaluate(r -> {
      assertEquals(r, "expected");
   });
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xUnit Test Patternsで言う、"Four Phase Test"を強制＆明示できるテスティングフレームワークを探している、ということですね。Javaそのものではありませんが、Groovyで記述するSpockというテスティングフレームワークででは、まさにそのような記述が可能になっています。

SpockではテストコードをGroovyで記述しますが、テスト対象のプロダクトコードはJavaで記述されていても問題ありません。

たとえば、質問にあるような疑似テストコードをSpock風に書くと以下のようになります。

```
void "test of hoge"() {
    given: // 関連するクラスのスタブやモックの作成コードのテスト準備コード
    Hoge hoge = Mock(Hoge)
    hoge.getXXX() >> "hogehoge"
    test.hoge = hoge

    when: // テスト実行のコード
    def result = test.target()

    then: // assertionのコード
    result == "expected"
}
```

Spockでは、

- ラベルによるFour Phase Testに従った記法
- Power Assertによるverifyの簡素化＆NG時の詳細表示
- 強力なParamterized Testサポート
- 標準でモック＆スタブをサポート
- Javaと親和性の高いGroovyによる柔軟な記述

などの特徴があります。

詳しい情報は、下記のURLからどうぞ。

- https://github.com/yamkazu/spock-workshop/tree/master/docs
- https://spock-framework-reference-documentation-ja.readthedocs.org/ja/latest/

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。xUnit Test Patternsというものがあるのですね、知りませんでした。すごく、有益ですね！確かに考えている内容では、Spockを利用するのが一番近そうです。ただ･･･後出し的な情報で申し訳ないのですが、大規模プロジェクト（100名越えている）でGroovyを使ってというのは少しハードルが高いのかなぁと思っています。